# What's the difference between ffprobe level and H.264 level?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec, ffprobe

ffprobe -show_streams input.mp4

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=hevc
codec_long_name=H.265 / HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding)
profile=Main
codec_type=video
...
level=120
...
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ffprobe indicates the stream codec is H.265 a.k.a. HEVC. The correct Wiki link is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding_tiers_and_levels

The codec standard requires the level be multiplied by 30 before it is stored in the bitstream. So, a readout of 120 corresponds to `120/30` = level `4`

Comment: See section `A.4` of the [ITU hevc](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.265) spec for this detail on levels.